# Acquiring input data of openjpeg program for verification

Tags: c, encoding

I was recently doing a project on accelerating the jpeg2000 image compression algorithm, However, when I used openjpeg, which is an open source project, to do the compression, I couldn't get the input data before the dwt module, The detail is shown below. The environment is Windows in Visual Studio 2022.

```
/* <summary>                            */
/* Forward 5-3 wavelet transform in 2-D. */
/* </summary>                           */
static INLINE OPJ_BOOL opj_dwt_encode_procedure(opj_thread_pool_t* tp,
        opj_tcd_tilecomp_t * tilec,
        opj_encode_and_deinterleave_v_fnptr_type p_encode_and_deinterleave_v,
        opj_encode_and_deinterleave_h_one_row_fnptr_type
        p_encode_and_deinterleave_h_one_row)
{
    OPJ_INT32 i;
    OPJ_INT32 *bj = 00;
    OPJ_UINT32 w;
    OPJ_INT32 l;

    OPJ_SIZE_T l_data_size;

    opj_tcd_resolution_t * l_cur_res = 0;
    opj_tcd_resolution_t * l_last_res = 0;
    const int num_threads = opj_thread_pool_get_thread_count(tp);
    OPJ_INT32 * OPJ_RESTRICT tiledp = tilec->data;

    w = (OPJ_UINT32)(tilec->x1 - tilec->x0);
    l = (OPJ_INT32)tilec->numresolutions - 1;

    l_cur_res = tilec->resolutions + l;
    l_last_res = l_cur_res - 1;

    l_data_size = opj_dwt_max_resolution(tilec->resolutions, tilec->numresolutions);
    /* overflow check */
    if (l_data_size > (SIZE_MAX / (NB_ELTS_V8 * sizeof(OPJ_INT32)))) {
        /* FIXME event manager error callback */
        return OPJ_FALSE;
    }
    l_data_size *= NB_ELTS_V8 * sizeof(OPJ_INT32);
    bj = (OPJ_INT32*)opj_aligned_32_malloc(l_data_size);
    /* l_data_size is equal to 0 when numresolutions == 1 but bj is not used */
    /* in that case, so do not error out */
    if (l_data_size != 0 && ! bj) {
        return OPJ_FALSE;
    }
    i = l;

    while (i--) {
        OPJ_UINT32 j;
        OPJ_UINT32 rw;           /* width of the resolution level computed   */
        OPJ_UINT32 rh;           /* height of the resolution level computed  */
        OPJ_UINT32
        rw1;      /* width of the resolution level once lower than computed one                                       */
        OPJ_UINT32
        rh1;      /* height of the resolution level once lower than computed one                                      */
        OPJ_INT32 cas_col;  /* 0 = non inversion on horizontal filtering 1 = inversion between low-pass and high-pass filtering */
        OPJ_INT32 cas_row;  /* 0 = non inversion on vertical filtering 1 = inversion between low-pass and high-pass filtering   */
        OPJ_INT32 dn, sn;

        rw  = (OPJ_UINT32)(l_cur_res->x1 - l_cur_res->x0);
        rh  = (OPJ_UINT32)(l_cur_res->y1 - l_cur_res->y0);
        rw1 = (OPJ_UINT32)(l_last_res->x1 - l_last_res->x0);
        rh1 = (OPJ_UINT32)(l_last_res->y1 - l_last_res->y0);

        cas_row = l_cur_res->x0 & 1;
        cas_col = l_cur_res->y0 & 1;

        sn = (OPJ_INT32)rh1;
        dn = (OPJ_INT32)(rh - rh1);


        // Print out the data before the DWT
        FILE* fp1;
        fp1 = fopen("D:/Imperial_study/spring_term/Individual_Project_jpeg2000/OPENjpeg/data.csv", "w");
        //OPJ_INT32 *data = tilec->data;  // Tile's data
        for (OPJ_UINT32 i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
            for (OPJ_UINT32 j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
                fprintf(fp1, "%d, ", tiledp[i * 512 + j]);  // print each pixels
            }
            fprintf(fp1, "\n");  // end and switch line
        }
        //close the file
        fclose(fp1);
/end///////////////////////////////////////////
```

In this dwt module, the tilec->data is the input data which is restricted to be accessed by tiledp.

In the processing loop, I accessed it by writing it to a file. Here comes the problem: I can print all other variables such as w, l which is defined previously. However, the result of the input data is a huge number which matrix looks like the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bSEG.png)

which is not supposed to be. The input data range should be within 0-255 which is 8 bit number. I‘ve figure out this problem, it's because the data is represented in IEEE 754 format and I use %d to output the data. therefore it shows a huge number which is the decimal format of the IEEE binary sequence. However, I'm still quite confused about why it shows IEEE 754 format. Normally the output should be the data number  it self which is 0 to 255 rather than in other format. Can someone explain how can I output the original data number instead of in IEEE format?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15168)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.